# Tensorflow classifier is not overfitting, accuracy on train set stays low

Tags: tensorflow, classification

This might be a weird question, buy here goes: I have a DNNClassifier in tensorflow that I ran with all sorts of parameters, and numbers of epochs. The weird thing that is happening is that, whatever I do, my accuracy on my train set stays quite low (It's a binary classifier, accuracy stays around 65%). I would expect that with at least some of the configurations I've tried (ones without regularization/dropout), I would've overfitted and reached a higher accuracy on my training set, but alas.

So, what does this mean? That I don't have enough data? That my network is not big enough to fit the data set? I tried doubling the size of my hidden layers, but it still stayed pretty much the same.

I have 23000 training examples, and currently have 3 layers of 100 neurons each.

Code can be found here: https://www.pastebucket.com/563290

Comment: You need to be more specific about your training data and what task you solve. With that said, your network is very small so perhaps you could use a larger network.

Comment: Try plotting your loss and see how it evolves over time, is it still decreasing ? Or has it already converged ?

Comment: @JonasAdler: I've tried networks up to 3 layers of 500 neurons. I am trying to predict the outcome of a tennis match. I'm getting about the same accuracy and loss on my test set as on my training set. I was trying to improve that test accuracy, but that feels like a flawed goal if I can't even reach higher accuracy on my training data set. I understand that this is not an easy task, but the fact that I wasn't even able to reach higher accuracy on my training data made me think I was doing something wrong.

Comment: @amo-ej1 The loss has converged after about 100-150 epochs, and is just not moving anymore much after that.

Comment: Could you post your code? This sounds weird.

Comment: @JonasAdler Code can be found here: https://www.pastebucket.com/563290 Current version is with 500 neurons in the layers and without regularization or dropout, to try to overfit :p The weird part is that some of my features should be very good indicators of match winner, as I'm using the betting odds as features, which are highly correlated with match winning. I started out with fewer features, and added a lot afterwards in the current code sample as an attempt to fit better. But I've had this problem the entire time, even when I had only 6 features.

Comment: I think it's the problem of optimization. Without careful *weight initialization* and learning rate policy, the training can not be optimized because of gradient explosion/vanishing problem. Some techniques like *Batch Normalization* can help some (but I am not sure how much it can help in your problem). On the other hand, for DNN, isn't it better to use like 50, 100, 50, 2 neurons (increase at first then decrease) for each layer respectively?

Comment: Increase -> decrease does seem to give a more logical looking learning curve. Will keep that for now. Training accuracy stays low though. If it's vanishing gradients, I can maybe try an ELU activation function instead of the relu I'm using now. Will give that a go.